# changing ternary operator into nonternary

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm new javascript(react) programmer, trying to change ternary operator into normal if else, here is my question : i want to add line through to the textDecoration property if it is completed, and 'else' i want nothing, the code i have for ternary operator is working but i want to change it to nonternary(normal if else), here is ternary version :

```js
function Todo({todo}) {
    return <div style={{
      textDecoration: tod.isCompleted ? 'line-through' : ''
    }} />;
}
```

here is what i tried to do :

```js
function Todo({todo}) {
  return <div style={{
    if (todo.isCompleted) {
      'line-through'
    } else {
      ''
    }} />;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering what's wrong with using the ternary? It's completely acceptable.

At any rate, you cannot have an if/else inside a JSX element like that. I would extract text decoration into a variable like so:

```js
function Todo({todo}){
  let textDecoration = '';
  if(todo.isCompleted){
    textDecoration = 'line-through';
  }
  return <div style={{textDecoration}}/>;
}
```

As a bit of fun, there is a proposal to have something kind-of like what you demonstrated. It's not in javascript yet, and I don't expect it to be anytime soon. But if you use babel, you can play with it if you wanted to. It's the do expression. You'd use it like so:

```js
function Todo({todo}){
  return <div style={{
    textDecoration: do {
        if(todo.isCompleted){
            'line-through';
        }
        else {
            '';
        }
    }
  }}/>;
}
```

Though, I don't really recommend it. I just thought I would provide it as a bit of fun knowledge. Here's a babel playground link to it: [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAFTgEzgCgN5XXAXwEpsAoRRAJwFMoRKkAeNGAN0QGcoBPAG2oC82MhQCQUagA8oAEWoQ4lAIawEALkQZEZUaJjBMeDADoYHAMJwAtgAd-EtCVK7RAcl4ww1ALRQAFpRwIADmfq4A3M6iBFHUvBzU2lFuEVEx0eSIBAQA9AB8kQRAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.11.0&externalPlugins=)

You can read up on the proposal here: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions